# How to share text to Facebook

Tags: iphone

In RootviewController of my application I have a textfield and a button. I write something in that text field and after that when I click on the button then that text should be shared in Facebook. How to do this??

Comment: Are you sharing knowledge with us or do you have any question ???

Comment: If this is a question about how to make such a page in an iPhone app, it's rather broad and you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: OK.. let me explain you.. My Question is "In RootviewController of my application I have a textfield and a button. I write something in that text field and after that when I click on the button then that text should shared in facebook." How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to integrate FB in your app to post your comments...

Comment: But I want to share the message without having the login page

Comment: Actually I am totally new in iphone, So if any one have any code/idea then please help me..

Comment: for that you need to login facebook account details in your device. using single signin feature you can access through app

Answer (score 0):

You must integrate Facebook SDK in order to do anything in user's account from iPhone app. After integrating and login You need to ask for permission "set_status" and after that you can show dialog for "set_status". That will show what exactly you want.